# ReactJs Context not updated, values always default

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context

- I have **parent wrapper component** and I added **react context inside** it.
- Inside that wrapper component I also have useEffect() hook which I use to fetch some values from API and then set these values to context.
- **Inside my child component** which is using context, **values for context are always default** ones. When I check in browser react tools it seems that values for context are updated but when I test it with console.log it always returns default ones.

**Parent component which has context inside:**

```
...
export const CorporateContext = createContext({corporateId: null, corporateRole: null, corporateAdmin: null, corporateSuperAdmin: null});

export const CorporateWrapper = ({ apiBaseUrl, children }) => {
    const [corporateContextDefaults, setCorporateContextDefaults] = 
    useState({corporateId: null, corporateRole: null, corporateAdmin: null, corporateSuperAdmin: null});

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            try {
                const json = await fetchCorporateUserDetails(apiBaseUrl);

                if (json.success !== true) {
                    console.log(json.message);
                  } else {
                    console.log(json.data) // <-- TESTED RESPONSE FROM API
                    setCorporateContextDefaults(json.data); // <-- UPDATE CONTEXT VALUES HOOK AND PASS IT BELOW TO CONTEXT PROVIDER
                  }

               
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e.message);
                }
            })();
    }, []);

    return (
        <CorporateContext.Provider value={corporateContextDefaults}>
        {children}
        </CorporateContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default CorporateWrapper;
```

**Child component which is using that context:**

```
const CorporateSettingsPage: React.FC<CorporateSettingsPageProps> = ({
  apiBaseUrl,
  campusBaseUrl,
  ecomBaseUrl,
}: CorporateSettingsPageProps) => {
  const corporateContext = useContext(CorporateContext);

  console.log('corporate context is:');    //<-- ALWAYS RETURNS DEFAULT VALUES
  console.log(corporateContext);


  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const json = await fetchCorporateSettings(apiBaseUrl, 
corporateContext.corporateId);
  ...
    })();
  }, [corporateContext]);

  return (
      <CorporateWrapper apiBaseUrl={apiBaseUrl}> // <--- PARENT COMPONENT WITH CONTEXT INSIDE
        <div>
           ...
           <SomeOtherComponent />   // <-- CONTEXT IS CORRECT HERE AND UPDATED VALUES ARE SHOWN
        </div>
      </CorporateWrapper>
  );
```

Comment: try adding a useEffect hook in the parent component that logs `corporateContextDefaults` every time it changes. In this way we exclude that the problem is not in the state but in the context. If it doesn't log anything or it logs the default value in the last update the problem is in the state

Comment: I tried. first console.log are default values and then second are values from api so correct. I updated my question. There is one more child component which have correct context values inside it, so context works fine there. Maybe my whole "Child Component" is not actually a child because inside that page I am wrapping page content inside wrapper component

Comment: If you are using your context in a non-child then you found your issue. Since your component won't be a child of the provider you defined, it will never receive your value

Comment: Now when I added that wrapper inside app.js file and remove it from file above, it works fine. Is that correct place just to wrap everything in app.js?

Comment: Context can be placed everywhere, the important thing is that you respect the fact that the consumer is a child of the component. Obviously putting every context inside your app.js can become soon difficult to maintain, so always try to thing "is this the correct place?". Maybe you will notice that is necessary to create another component

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers! Obviously I put my wrapper component inside the page which should use that component and it didnt worked as that wrapper is not actually a parent. So how I can create parent component for specific pages and add context there? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69411923/reactjs-create-parent-component-for-specific-pages-to-be-able-to-add-react-co

Comment: Creating a component is pretty easy. Think for instance of a page with a list of songs on the left and a song playing on the right. Since these two components are on the same page, it make sense create a dedicated page, store the context and the state there, and then share with both components the same context. In the end you just have to use the nearest parent of the components you are using

Answer (score 2):

Try to do these things:

1. First ensure that the state is correctly updating. This should be enough to debug:

```
useEffect(()=>{
console.log(corporateContextDefaults);
},[corporateContextDefaults])
```

2. If the state is updating correctly the problem is in your Provider->Consumer relation.

Verify that your consumer is a child of the providing component.

Comment: Yep, that is the thing -> If the state is updating correctly the problem is in your Provider->Consumer relation. Wrong relation

Comment: @Denis2310 I was just pointing out a possible procedure for future readers that might read in future, now I will answer above

Answer (score 2):

React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) state: "All consumers that are descendants of a Provider will re-render whenever the Provider’s value prop changes.". Your `CorporateSettingsPage` component won't be able to `useContext(CorporateContext)` because it's not a descendant of `CorporateWrapper` whereas `SomeOtherComponent` which is a descendant will be able to.