# How can I create a parent component for specific pages (to be able to add react context inside parent)?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context

- I have specific set of pages which will use specific react context.
- I dont want to create context inside app.js root file, because I will use that context only on specific set of pages.

How I can create parent component (wrapper) which I will wrap around these specific pages and then add context inside that parent?

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this with the HOC concept:

```
const Context = React.createContext({ ... });

const withPageContext = (PageComponent) => {
    const Wrapper = (props) => {
        return (
            <Context.Provider value={...}>
                <PageComponent {...props} />
            </Context.Provider>
        )
    };

    return hoistStatics(Wrapper, PageComponent, {
        // `getInitialProps` not in hoist static list, so we add it here to prevent override
        getInitialProps: true,
    })
};
```

Then it can be used in your `pages/*` like this:

```
const MyPage = () => {
    const ctx = useContext(Context);
};

export default withPageContext(MyPage);
```

Comment: And now for example I have one page, how can I ensure that page can use that context? If I just wrap <PageContext> in return method in my page, I cannot use context in that file because it will be available only to page child components which are wrapped with that PageContext. Look at the code in second container, I tried that but it will be available to page child components but I want it to be available also in that file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69411744/reactjs-context-not-updated-values-always-default

Comment: @Denis2310 I see. Check my edited answer with an HOC approach

Comment: That is what I thought about, something like that with HOC component. But what is this actually?     return hoistStatics(Wrapper, PageComponent, {
        // `getInitialProps` not in hoist static list, so we add it here to prevent override
        getInitialProps: true,
    })

Comment: Without this your HOC will shadow the `static` properties on your Page component. But this only happen if you're using some "older" Next.js APIs.

The newer APIs are directly exported (e.g `export async function getStaticProps(context) {`) which makes HOC shadowing a non-issue. https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching